# My whole View is getting refreshed on clicking on the single item from the list

Tags: android, kotlin

Below is the code I am using:

Here root is the parent ViewGroup

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            mExpandedPosition = if (isExpanded) -1 else position
            TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(root)
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
```

Issue: There are multiple entries in my list when I click on one entry to expand the whole view refreshes.

Comment: Because of this `notifyDataSetChanged()`. It is telling the adapter that `Data set has been changed` so it is refreshing the whole list.

Comment: Use `notifyItemChanged(position)` instead of `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: Ya I tried that but now it is refreshing the individual item as in not the structure totally but the item I click on is getting refreshed which doesn't look smooth

Answer (score 0):

Using `notifyItemRangeChanged(position,itemCount)` worked for me